# transform: rotate is creating unwanted white space

Tags: html, css, whitespace, css-transforms

I have a page which uses transform: rotate, but leaves a large whitespace where the element would have been were it not rotated. I have found a couple of other people asking a similar question, but I have been unable to adapt those answers to solve my present problem. I think that they probably contain the correct solution, and I am just making a mistake in trying to apply it to my case:

[Css rotate div creates white space on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922526/css-rotate-div-creates-white-space-on-top)

[White space around css3 scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385578/white-space-around-css3-scale)

As you can see, there's a lot of white space beneath the rotated text. I would like the text to end up in the same place, without that white space.

```css
div.titles {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  left: 367px;
  height: 260px;
  top: -4px;
}

p.volumes {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arial Narrow";
  line-height: 220%;
  font-size: 10;
}

ul.titles {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.titles li {
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: "Subway", "Courier", "serif";
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<BODY>
  <DIV class="titles" id="sideways" style="position: relative;">";
    <p class="volumes" id="volumes"></p>";

    <ul class="titles">
      <li>ale.imzqzfojdobcggydk</li>
      <li>mouwl sxjjwrk,osbl</li>
      <li>cqjpjfeqhgovtto</li>
    </ul>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
```

Comment: I think you should play a little more with transform and transform-origin so you can have your expected results, I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2h12qm5/1/) so you can see what I'm talking, I'm not sure if that is what you wanted to do, so I'm not putting it as an answer. You can get more information of [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: I'm asking how I can have this same rotation without leaving behind the white space at the bottom. I took a look at your edits @valarauko, but it appears that the white space is still there.

Comment: You can get rid of the white space by setting your title div with an absolute position, it did not worked with relative position because the container still has the objects height reference. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2h12qm5/2/). I think that's what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By making the rotated element 'block' rather than 'inline-block', the space below disappears.

```
div.titles {
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    left: 367px;
    height: 260px;
    top: -4px;
}
```

As you can see in this edited [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2h12qm5/4/), new text added falls right below the rotated text without a gap.

Answer (score 2):

New Solution For You, If above CSS not work for you so use this trick. Add a Span element in the TD element. you can add margin-left and right.

```
<td>

<span style="float: left; 
transform: rotate(-90deg); 
white-space: nowrap; 
width: 30px;">
VACATE ORDER
</span>

</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this CSS property::::::

```
.div.titles {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20px;
}
```